# Python framework that performs acceptance testing, generates rdetailed logs and compatible with XRAY and Jenkins

Tags: python, software-testing

I am looking for an Python test framework that can automate my existing Python testcases and perform acceptance testing, generate logs step by step in the testcase, generate detailed test report and also something that I can seamlessly integrate with Jenkins and XRAY.
I also wish that the framework has plugins to update the Jira's on XRAY.

I evaluated Robot but it seems like a wrapper on the Python language which is more syntax based and not as generic as python and the our team members are not voting for it.